# Powershell - How can I extract the element of local html files using XPath

Tags: html, powershell, xpath

I'm trying scraping some of the data from the IMDB website. The data I want to extract is the title (movie name), release year and plot summary of some movies. I have batch downloaded all the pages I want to extract from to my hard drive and when I inspect the element of the page I want to extract on Google Chrome, its full XPath selector is something like this for movie name:

```
/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/h1/text()
```

I have spend time find the code for the problem but no answer (as far as I know of). I was reading some of the code like

```
$html = Get-Content -Path "E:\POWERSHELL\IMDB pages\tt0062940.html" -Raw
$htmlFile = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile"
$htmlFile.IHTMLDocument2_write($html)
```

but I do not know what to do now. Can someone please tell me know if we can use XPath to select HTML elements in Powershell to parse and extract the information from local files.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`Select-Xml`** as shown below.

```
$Path = "E:\POWERSHELL\IMDB pages\tt0062940.html"
$h1Text = (Select-Xml -Path $Path -Xpath /html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/h1).Node.InnerText
$h1Text
```

or you can wrap the path in double quotes so that you don't have to worry about the spaces between folder name.

```
$h1Text = (Select-Xml -Path "E:\POWERSHELL\IMDB pages\tt0062940.html" -Xpath /html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/h1).Node.InnerText
$h1Text
```

Comment: Your cmd let can't be run because the directory name contains space. I don't know how to fix it though.

Comment: Try with the updated answer. Other option is wrapping the path in double quotes `"`.

Comment: I move the file to a folder on the K: drive and type your command `$h1Text = (Select-Xml -Path "K:\MY DOCUMENTS\POWERSHELL\IMDB pages\tt0062940.html" -Xpath /html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/h1).Node.InnerText
$h1Text` but it said `Select-Xml : The file 'K:\MY DOCUMENTS\POWERSHELL\IMDB pages\tt0062940.html' cannot be read: An error occurred while 
parsing EntityName. Line 25, position 49. .. + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (K:\MY DOCUMENTS...\tt0062940.html:String) [Select-Xml], Argument..` I just quote some words. What do I do now.

Comment: check your `html` file is valid. Seems to be there is some issue in line # 25, column# 49 in your html

Comment: What is the "String" thing here then `\tt0062940.html:String) [Select-Xml], Argument..` Well I don't have any right on the HTML file. I just input the link into IDM app and download it. If you want I will upload the files then give the link.

Comment: Sure,please share the file. If it's does not contain any sensitive data.

Comment: The link to file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fAl7YKNV4IUke3YnayfGwkXID-y3V_RG/view?usp=drivesdk. Pls tell me know if anything is wrong.

Comment: Unable to access the file.

Comment: You downloaded it and can't open it or you can't access the link. The link still work for me and I think I have zipped the files in a right way.